# fillcolor property colorstring hsl string not working

Tags: python, colors, plotly, geopandas, choropleth

I have a colorscale

```
colorscale2 = ['hsl(-2221.0, 60.0%, 98.0%)', 
               'hsl(-2192.0460921843687, 59.791583166332664%, 97.88777555110221%)', 
               'hsl(-2163.0921843687374, 59.58316633266533%, 97.7755511022044%)', 
               'hsl(-2134.138276553106, 59.37474949899799%, 97.66332665330661%)', 
               'hsl(-2105.184368737475, 59.166332665330664%, 97.55110220440882%)', 
               'hsl(-2076.2304609218436, 58.95791583166333%, 97.43887775551102%)', 
               'hsl(-2047.2765531062123, 58.74949899799599%, 97.32665330661322%)', 
               'hsl(-2018.3226452905812, 58.54108216432866%, 97.21442885771543%)', 
               'hsl(-1989.36873747495, 58.33266533066132%, 97.10220440881764%)', 
               'hsl(-1960.4148296593187, 58.124248496993985%, 96.98997995991984%)', 
               'hsl(-1931.4609218436874, 57.91583166332666%, 96.87775551102204%)', 
               'hsl(-1902.5070140280561, 57.70741482965932%, 96.76553106212425%)', 
               'hsl(-1873.5531062124248, 57.498997995991985%, 96.65330661322645%)', 
               'hsl(-1844.5991983967936, 57.29058116232465%, 96.54108216432866%)', 
               'hsl(-1815.6452905811623, 57.08216432865731%, 96.42885771543087%)', 
               'hsl(-1786.6913827655312, 56.87374749498998%, 96.31663326653306%)', 
               'hsl(-1757.7374749499, 56.66533066132264%, 96.20440881763527%)', 
               'hsl(-1728.7835671342687, 56.45691382765531%, 96.09218436873748%)']
```

but i recieve the following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 1100, in validate_coerce
    self.raise_invalid_val(v)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py", line 243, in raise_invalid_val
    valid_clr_desc=self.description()))

ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'fillcolor' property of scatter
        Received value: 'hsl(-2221.0, 60.0%, 98.0%)'

    The 'fillcolor' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
            cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
            darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
            darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
            darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
            darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
            darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
            dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
            floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
            ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
            greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
            ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
            lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
            lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
            lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
            lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
            lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
            linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
            mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
            mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
            mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
            mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
            oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
            orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
            palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
            plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
            royalblue, saddlebrown, salmon, sandybrown,
            seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver, skyblue,
            slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow, springgreen,
            steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato, turquoise,
            violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke, yellow,
            yellowgreen
```

What is the problem? Ive included my entire code below,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chessybo/Oil-Spill-map/468bd2205d85c7b0bfb4ebcd4bc4bf0ba408efb4/RRC_Spill_table/county_name%20%26%20fips%20%26%20net%20loss%20%26%20count%20(ordered%20by%20district%20%26%20grouped).csv')

colorscale2 = ['hsl(-2221.0, 60.0%, 98.0%)', 
               'hsl(-2192.0460921843687, 59.791583166332664%, 97.88777555110221%)', 
               'hsl(-2163.0921843687374, 59.58316633266533%, 97.7755511022044%)', 
               'hsl(-2134.138276553106, 59.37474949899799%, 97.66332665330661%)', 
               'hsl(-2105.184368737475, 59.166332665330664%, 97.55110220440882%)', 
               'hsl(-2076.2304609218436, 58.95791583166333%, 97.43887775551102%)', 
               'hsl(-2047.2765531062123, 58.74949899799599%, 97.32665330661322%)', 
               'hsl(-2018.3226452905812, 58.54108216432866%, 97.21442885771543%)', 
               'hsl(-1989.36873747495, 58.33266533066132%, 97.10220440881764%)', 
               'hsl(-1960.4148296593187, 58.124248496993985%, 96.98997995991984%)', 
               'hsl(-1931.4609218436874, 57.91583166332666%, 96.87775551102204%)', 
               'hsl(-1902.5070140280561, 57.70741482965932%, 96.76553106212425%)', 
               'hsl(-1873.5531062124248, 57.498997995991985%, 96.65330661322645%)', 
               'hsl(-1844.5991983967936, 57.29058116232465%, 96.54108216432866%)', 
               'hsl(-1815.6452905811623, 57.08216432865731%, 96.42885771543087%)', 
               'hsl(-1786.6913827655312, 56.87374749498998%, 96.31663326653306%)', 
               'hsl(-1757.7374749499, 56.66533066132264%, 96.20440881763527%)', 
               'hsl(-1728.7835671342687, 56.45691382765531%, 96.09218436873748%)']

endpts = [120, 240, 360, 480, 600, 720, 840, 960, 1080, 1225, 2225, 3225, 4225, 5225, 6225]
fips = df['fips'].tolist()
values = df['Net spill volume (BBL)'].tolist()
count=df['number_of_oil_spills'].tolist()
x=values



fig = create_choropleth(
    fips=fips, values=values,
    binning_endpoints=endpts,
    colorscale=colorscale2,
    show_state_data=False,
    show_hover=True, centroid_marker={'opacity': 0},
    scope=['TX'],
    state_outline={'color': 'rgb(15, 15, 55)', 'width': 3},
    asp=2.9, title='Oil Spills from 12/1/16 - 5/14/18',
    legend_title='Net spill Volume (BBL)'
)

fig['layout']['legend'].update({'x': 0})
fig['layout']['annotations'][0].update({'x': -0.12, 'xanchor': 'left'})
py.plot(fig, filename='oil spill net loss')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp, the first value from hsl is hue which has a range from 0 to 360.0.

The data that you have is not expected by relevant functions. Perhaps you may want to look into that and perform some pre-processing.